# drawRect on iPad causing memory problems

Tags: ios, drawrect

I have a 5-tab Tab Bar Controller iPad application.
One of the tabs (EKG) is causing memory issues. I have run Instruments and all that I can see is that `malloc` allocations are constantly increasing and after about 12-mins all of my View Controller first get `didReceiveMemoryWarning` level 1, followed by level 2, and then `SigAbort 0 termination`.

The way that the app is designed to work is when the EKG tab is active a `setNeedsDisplay` is triggered every 200-ms in order to draw (plot) EKG samples across the screen. When I just let the app run normally it is terminated after about 12-mins.

However, if I keep the `setNeedsDisplay` in and comment out the code in `drawRect` it will run
forever. I am not aware of any memory allocations in my 'drawRect' but someone is doing these `mallocs` Below is my `drawRect` code:

```
- (void) drawRect : (CGRect) rect 
{
    int i, ii, x = 0, xx, y;        

    fEcgDraw = YES;     
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext ();
    CGContextSetLineWidth (context, 1);             
    HH = 376;                               
    if (fEcgErase == YES)                           
    {
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor (context,      
                     [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
/*==============================================================================*/
/* Erase the last screen.                                                       */
/*==============================================================================*/
        for (i = 0; i < 120; i++)                   
        {        
            CGContextMoveToPoint (context,          
                          ECGX[x],
                          (HH - ECGS[x]));      
            CGContextAddLineToPoint (context, ECGX[(x + 1)],    
                         (HH - ECGS[((x + 1) % 119)])); 
            x++;                            
        }   // end - for (i = 0; i < 120; i++)
        CGContextStrokePath (context);          
        fEcgErase = NO;             
    }   // end - if (fEcgErase == YES)
    else if (fECGLOOP)                  
    {
        xx = 1;             
        x = 0;                  
        y = YY;                         
        ii = 0;             
        for (i =
        { 
//          if (xx == 1)                
            {
/*==============================================================================*/
/* First erase the prior ECG A/D plot value.                                    */
/*==============================================================================*/
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor (context,  
                        [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);  
                CGContextMoveToPoint (context,          
                            ECGX[x],    
                            (HH - ECGS[x]));
                CGContextAddLineToPoint (context,       
                            ECGX[(x + 1)],      
                            (HH - ECGS[((x + 1))]));
                CGContextStrokePath (context);          
/*==============================================================================*/
/* Now plot the next ECG A/D plot value.                                        */
/*==============================================================================*/
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor (context,  
                        [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);  
                CGContextMoveToPoint (context,      
                              ECGX[x],      
                              (HH - ECGY[y]));  
                CGContextAddLineToPoint (context,   
                             ECGX[(x + 1)],     
                             (HH - ECGY[((y + 1) % 119)])); 
                CGContextStrokePath (context);          
                ECGS[x] = ECGY[y];      
                x++;                
                y = ((y + 1) % 119);        
            }   // end - if (xx == 1)
        }       // end - for (i = 0; i < 120; i++)
        y = ((y + count1) % 119);               
        YY = y;                         
        count1 = 0;                 
    }   // end - if (fEcgErase == YES)
    fEcgDraw = NO;                              

}   // end - 'drawRect'
/*===============================END OF FUNCTION================================*/
```

Comment: I have already tried commenting out the 'drawRect' and leaving in the 'setNeedsDisplay' and this makes the problem go away. I am not understanding your comment about iver & gvars, espcially gvars since by definition they have only a single instance. As far as ivars I don't understand how there could be multiples since there is no class instantiation that would alloc more ivars.

Answer (score 2):

Problem has been solved by adding ' CGContextClosePath' before each 'CGContextStrokePath' and the app will now run forever without any 'didReceiveMemoryWarning'.

-Gil Goodridge

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any leaks in `drawRect:`. You can use the ObjectAllocation's instrument and look at the backtraces on the `malloc` calls to see what is requesting them. You can also leave in your `setNeedsDisplay` and comment out your entire `drawRect:`. If memory still grows, then it's somewhere else.

I would also look at the impact that the ivars or global vars you're changing might have on other threads. For instance, is any other thread reading `fEcgDraw` or `HH` and might be failing to release memory due to these being messed with in `drawRect:`?

Comment: I thought this problem was resolved by adding 'CGContextClosePath' and alas it is not. Here is the latest, if I run my app under Instruments it never fails nor does it report any leaks, etc. I have tried commenting out various parts of my 'drawRect' if an effort to get closer to the problem. Here is what I've found -- if I comment all of 'drawRect' it doesn't fail, if I comment out only the 'CGContextStrokePath' it never fails - so my conclusion is that the culprit (that is losing memory) is 'CGContextStrokePath'. I have no idea how to correct this problem. Any advice?

Comment: In Instruments, using the Allocations instrument, you should see overall memory usage grow in size, and you should note which kind of object it is. You mentioned it's a malloc, but the size of it is important, and you can tell the instrument to track the allocation stack frames so you can see what is generating them.

Comment: This problem is really strange, the latest is that this problem only happens when I run the app from Xcode (debug or no debug) -- when I run it standalone it runs forever (tested to 1 1/2 hours) without a problem.